# How do I create a form that updates when users fill in their own data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I saw the following on a competitor's website: it's a form with on the left side a few user inputs, and the right side outputs this into a pre made "document" which is a preview on how it would look. This would look really cool if I could add it into my website, and if people could download said file.

[Link for reference](https://opzeggers.com/lexa/) on how it should work.

I tried to understand the code with inspect element, however there are a lot of plugins being used which I can't figure out are necessary for this specific bit of code, or just to run the site in general and have this form sent to the mail of the user

I am eager to learn a coding language - what would be a good one to tackle this issue?

Comment: For stackoverflow you will need to program something yourself first, and put your code in the question. If you're willing to pay you could head over to https://www.codementor.io

Comment: There are many ways to go about it. If you want to download it in a print-quality format then the output file needs to be PDF or SVG, and any graphics/glyphs need to be vector (with exceptions for bitmaps at the right DPI for printing). Just installing a plugin is not likely to cut the mustard here - it's a non-trivial problem needing custom programming.

Comment: I was going to tackle this problem myself - I favoured running Inkscape in a Docker container and sending XML files to it for conversion to PDF (print) or PNG (web).

Answer (score 0):

So the site that you have linked is build with WordPress and the [Elementor plugin](https://elementor.com/)

If you want to start building such a site on your own then u have 2 options.

option 1: you do the same as what the website did. Easily learn how to use WordPress with youtube tutorials.

option 2: you start learning html, css and js so you can start building your own website with your own design. I recommend using [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) for starting.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer, never had i imagined the solution to be so easy. I'll look into wordpress and if thats worth my time, but i'll also go to W3Schools and see what i can learn from there